# Don't show network drives using FileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, fileopendialog

Right now when I use FileOpenDialog it takes quiet some time to open, I tested it and it seems that it happens when the user have too many network drives. Is there a way to not show them or at least make them async so it doesn't take too much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with plain framework possibilities.

The `FileOpenDialog` and `FileSaveDialog` are based on the same `FileDialog` class. This class does not allow filter on drives. You can find a possible workaround in this thread: [WPF SaveFileDialog - Restrict Drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264332/wpf-savefiledialog-restrict-drives)